# unit of work and repository pattern and dispose database context

Tags: c#

I have unit of work class, I have there method to dispose database context. But I also pass database context to repository class - NotesRepository - should I also dispose context in NotesRepository class or it isn't necessary because this context was disposed in unit of work class?

```
public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    private DatabaseContext context = new DatabaseContext();
    private NotesRepository notesRepository;

    public NotesRepository NotesRepository
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.notesRepository == null)
            {
                this.notesRepository = new NotesRepository(context);
            }
            return notesRepository;
        }
    }


    private bool disposed = false;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                context.Dispose();
            }
        }
        this.disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

and this is repository class:

```
public class NotesRepository
{
    private DatabaseContext context;

    public NotesRepository(DatabaseContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }


    public IQueryable<Notes> GetAllNotes()
    {
        return (from x in context.Notes
                orderby x.CreateDate descending
                select x);
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend doing this inside your UnitOfWork class

```
using(var ctx = new DatabaseContext())
{
  var repo = new NotesRepo(ctx);
}
```

Now it will be disposed approriately through the using - without needing to dispose it in the repository